Do ICAO rules allow a pilot to level-off during a descent to comply with the 10,000 ft speed restriction?
I understand under FAA rules in the NAS a pilot may level-off during a descent, without additional coordination, to comply with the 250KIAS below 10,000’ speed restriction…

(AIM 4-4-10) …”If it is necessary to level off at an intermediate altitude during climb or descent, advise ATC, except when leveling off at 10,000 feet MSL on descent, or 2,500 feet above airport elevation (prior to entering a Class C or Class D surface area), when required for speed reduction.” && “NOTE - Leveling off at 10,000 feet MSL on descent or 2,500 feet above airport elevation (prior to entering a Class C or Class D surface area) to comply with 14 CFR Section 91.117 airspeed restrictions is commonplace. Controllers anticipate this action and plan accordingly. Leveling off at any other time on climb or descent may seriously affect air traffic handling by ATC. Consequently, it is imperative that pilots make every effort to fulfill the above expected actions to aid ATC in safely handling and expediting traffic.”

Is this same allowance codified anywhere in ICAO/EASA rules? Thanks for the help!

Welcome to Aviation.SE!

Is any temporary leveling-off actually explicitly forbidden other than it "may seriously affect air traffic handling by ATC"?

At least in the AIM…I read this as prescriptive, which is located just prior to the quote in my question, “If at anytime the pilot is unable to climb or descend at a rate of at least 500 feet a minute, advise ATC.”

No, this allowance is not codified in ICAO or EASA regulations, however, in practise the note from your quote is equally applicable here.
